# Does C99 standard define observable behavior as C++03 does?

Tags: c, c99, compiler-optimization, language-lawyer

In C++03 Standard 1.9/6 there's this definition of *observable behavior*

> The observable behavior of the abstract machine is its sequence of reads and writes to volatile data and calls to library I/O functions.

and The Standard goes to length explaining that the compiler must preserve *observable behavior* while doing optimizations.

However there's no such or similar definition in C99 draft I'm looking at. The only time *observable behavior* is mentioned is 6.7.3/7

> The intended use of the restrict qualifier (like the register storage class) is to promote
>   optimization, and deleting all instances of the qualifier from a conforming program does
>   not change its meaning (i.e., observable behavior)

Is there a definition of what exactly the compiler must preserve when optimizing a C99 program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my draft, §3.4, defines **behavior** as "external appearance or action". "Observable behavior" seems to be a pleonasm that occurs exactly once.

§5.1.2.3, Program execution, further defines the behavior of C programs:

> The semantic descriptions in this International Standard describe the behavior of an abstract machine in which issues of optimization are irrelevant.

It then goes on to define side-effects as "changes in the state of the execution environment" caused by "[a]ccessing a volatile object, modifying an object, modifying a file, or calling a function that does any of those operations". Side-effects are sequenced at sequence points.

This seems to be stricter than C++ in that "modifying an object", i.e. writing to memory, is (observable) behavior in C.

As for allowed optimization:

> In the abstract machine, all expressions are evaluated as specified by the semantics. An
>   actual implementation need not evaluate part of an expression if it can deduce that its
>   value is not used and that no needed side effects are produced (including any caused by
>   calling a function or accessing a volatile object).

"Needed side-effects" are then listed in the following point:

> - At sequence points, volatile objects are stable in the sense that previous accesses are
>     complete and subsequent accesses have not yet occurred.
> - At program termination, all data written into files shall be identical to the result that
>     execution of the program according to the abstract semantics would have produced.
> - The input and output dynamics of interactive devices shall take place as specified in
>     7.19.3.

The paragraph concludes with a list of examples; §7.19.3 describes files in the context of `stdio`.

Comment: What puzzles me is that side effect includes "modifying an object". The optimization paragraph doesn't mention evaluation reordering. So it can't reordering the following statements in any case:
    a = 1;
    b = 1;
Because ";" is a consequence point, the side effect (a = 1) has to happen before it.